# Gnome not locking screen automatically

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

I cannot manage to lock the screen automatically after a given time.
I running `gnome 3.22.2` with `lightdm`

I found quite confusing the configuration as it is spread across many setting/app:

1. Settings -> Power

   - Blank screen (time)
2. Settings -> Privacy

   - Screen Lock (yes/no)
3. Light locker

   - Blank screen after (time)
   - Switch screen off after (time)

I have configured startup applications:

- Light Locker
- `xset s 60 dpms 420 0 0`

What is wrong ?
How I am suppose to configure all above settings ?

**UPDATE**
On [Antergos](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/5473/gnome-not-locking-screen-automatically/2) forum I got this answer:

> Under lightDM all you have to do is disable all native Gnome power
>   settings and use only the Light Locker ones That is, unless you prefer
>   to use GDM instead.

So I set

- Power: Black screen NEVER
- Privacy: Screen Lock NO
- then set light locker timers, the screen lock correctly

**New problem**
… but then if I open again light locker my setting are gone and the screen stop to lock correctly

[image]

Comment: Are you using gdm or any other login manager?

Comment: as I wrote in the question I am using lightdm

Comment: It will be easier to shift to gdm other than to follow a workaround...  But if you wish to keep using lightdm I can post a workaround

Comment: @CedaEI go on please, I want to stay on lightdm if possible

Comment: Using lightdm with screen lock is unsecure. If you still want to use lightdm with screenlock, you can use `dm-tool lock` and create some scripts to lock screen with it.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86275/159917) on UNIX and Linux will help you out. 
Synopsis : you would need to use `gnome-screensaver` package. You need to manually install `gnome-screensaver` package

Comment: light locker is fork of `gnome-screensaver`, `gnome-screensaver` has been dropped after gnome 3.6 ( you should read the link you posted )

Comment: You can manually install gnome-screensaver

Comment: did you try that ? is it fixing the problem ?

Comment: Yes I am myself using the same.....

Comment: ok, please add this to your answer and the version of gnome you are using ( the system doesn't allow me to change my vote unless you edit )

Comment: You haven't un-downvoted my answer